# Using SSM Secret Strings to create a Glue Connection fails in CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-cdk

I am using cdk to define my ETL pipelines. The first step of the pipeline is to create crawlers that connect to RDS instances via JDBC connections to fetch the schema metadata.

I am trying to create a `glue.CfnConnection` where I pass in the `connectionProperties` `USERNAME` and `PASSWORD` which need to be fetched from SSM as Secret Strings.

I tried various ways to fetch the secrets using `ssm.StringParameter.valueForSecureStringParameter()` as outlined here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/get_ssm_value.html

I also tried using `ssm.StringParameter.fromSecureStringParameterAttributes()` as outlined here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-ssm-readme.html

When I synthesize the template it renders the values correctly for dynamic referencing:

```
"ConnectionProperties": {
  "JDBC_CONNECTION_URL": "url",
  "USERNAME": "{{resolve:ssm-secure:<secret-name>/username:version}}",
  "PASSWORD": "{{resolve:ssm-secure:<secret-name>/password:version}}"
}
```

But when I try to deploy this, I get the error: `SSM Secure reference is not supported`, which led me to this, which suggests dynamic referencing is not supported for all Cfn resources: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I am using SecretsManager to store username and password and that works for me:

```
"ConnectionProperties": {
  "JDBC_CONNECTION_URL": "url",
  "USERNAME": "{{resolve:secretsmanager:<secret-name>}}",
  "PASSWORD": "{{resolve:secretsmanager:<secret-name>}}"
}
```